# Is Skyrim Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, game

Skyrim is a game that has magic in it and gods. In the game, you believe in the gods and follow their orders but I do not think you prostrate to them. The women in the game are dressed like normal women you see today on the streets of America, England etc. You are also able to see the gods. There is also a little bit of swearing but not extremely insulting words like Fu** y**. It has shirk too. Is this haram?

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple angles where video games are problematic.

First, they can easily lead to wasting time, because it's easy to become sucked into the game and forget about time.

Next, most games use random number generators which are akin to dice. Many role playing games are based on Dungeons and Dragons, which uses dice. A hadith says that the Prophet, sal Allahu alaihi wasalam, said that playing dice games is like washing your hands with pig's blood.

The issue with statues having power and magic spells is definitely also problematic. In many games you get healing and strength from cross symbols. This makes a subconscious positive connection to the cross when really we should consider it as a symbol of shirk, a sin worse than murder or rape.

Also, usually there is music in these games that uses musical instruments. A student of Abu Hanifa said that music is the wine of the soul and its effect is worse than that of alcohol. It's easy to get desensitized to this and forget.

Also, the way women dress in the West is not really okay, it is connected to the high divorce/break up rates and associated mental health/social problems.

You have to consider it like this- any media- books, poetry, music, movies, video games- are a form of communication. Think of it kind of like if someone wrote you an email, and you read it. In a way, it's like you are opening your mind to the ideas of the people who made it.

The makers of Skyrim are clearly mostly not Muslim or not very practising, and when you turn the game on it's kind of like you are inviting them into your home. They put a lot of energy into making the game, and this will have an effect on your personality, and it is sure to make you more like them.

I don't know if I can definitively say it is haram, but what is sure is that there are MANY many different ways to use our limited time on this earth that would have a MUCH better effect on our souls, which is why I've been struggling for years to cut back on video games.

If you can toggle the music off, do, because this reduces the addictive effect and makes quitting easier.

Barak Allahu feek